# Other than CO2 release, what are the disadvantages of precipitating metal carbonates using NaHCO3 instead of Na2CO3?

Tags: solubility, metal

Be, Mg, Ba, Zn, Ni, Ca, Cu, Fe, Mn, Cd, Pb, Hg, Al carbonate salts are all insoluble.

I (perhaps naïvely) believe that I could precipitate carbonates from those mixing a soluble salts of these (e.g. CaCl2) with Na2CO3.

I (perhaps naïvely) believe that it would also work using NaHCO3, yielding CO2 and H2O as additional byproduct(s).

So I'm wondering, what are the advantages of using Na2CO3 over NaHCO3 for the purposes of precipitating carbonate salts of these metals? or, conversely, what are the disadvantages of precipitating metal carbonates using NaHCO3 instead of Na2CO3?

Comment: Note that bicarbonates of Ca and Mg, (possibly of some others as well), are soluble, they are bases of water carbonate(temporary) hardness.

Comment: @Poutnik: Thanks Poutnik, I didn't think of bicarbonates at all. So the CO2 released from NaHCO3 would induce the formation of a portion of soluble metal bicarbonates alongside their carbonate salts, which would decrease the yield for the latter? Do you have an idea of the order of the proportion between the bicarbonates and simple carbonates at room temperature (i.e. is it a significant loss?) Would performing the reaction in a near vacuum help circumvent this issue (maybe by preventing the presence of dissolved CO2, in addition to eliminating reactions at the solution's surface)?

Comment: There can be full loss. Why not to use carbonates, or Bicarbonates with hydroxide ? General rule is to maximize concentration of ions, that you expect to be in precipitate.

Comment: @Poutnik I can get bicarbonate with ~ twice lower levels of impurities than carbonate. So I'd like to go with the bicarbonate. I could either produce carbonate from it in the oven (though it would cost a lot of electricity), or use it directly in place of carbonate. Another aspect is that I think bicarbonate is a better way to store a carbonate source (as it needs to go through two steps to decompose into Na2O vs only one for Na2CO3). Having the metal carbonation reaction occur in a vacuum would cost very little energy compared to heating up the bicarbonate, if that would be of any help.

Comment: I had in mind addition of hydroxide to bicarbonate, or vice versa, to produce carbonate, before mixing with metal salts.

Comment: @Poutnik I'm not sure I understand your last comment. How can I produce hydroxide? Should I slowly hydrate CaO > then add Na2CO3 > filter out the precipitating CaCO3 > mix the NaOH solution with NaHCO3? and then add the metal salt?

Comment: I was not speaking about producing hydroxide, but carbonate.

Comment: @Poutnik But how do you add hydroxide to the solution to produce carbonate?

Comment: Hmmm, are you sure chemistry is the right thing for you ?

Comment: But because of limited solubility if sodium bicarbonate , it is better to add bicarbonate to solution of computed equivalent mass of sodium hydroxide..